# Why are my satellite images always appearing with null values on GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Mine is a simple operation of viewing satellite images in Google Earth Engine. I would like to view Sentinel 2 TOA images on GEE but clipped to a bounding box on the map. So I create the bounding box on the GEE map and saved it as a feature collection with a variable name `machakos` - place in my country.

Therefore I proceed to load the most cloudfree Sentinel 2 image for January 2021.

```
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31')
    .filterBounds(machakos)
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
    .first();

var macha = sentinel.clipToCollection(machakos);
print('Machakos details: ', macha);

Map.addLayer(sentinel, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'sentinel');
Map.addLayer(macha, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'machakos');
```

Problem is, both `var sentinel` which contains the full satellite tile and the hopefully clipped `var macha` tile both appear black in the GEE map. I even tried putting in `min: 0` and `max: 0.3` parameters to no avail (both appear when min max values are input). I thought I was doing everthing right. If the `var sentinel` could have appeared, I would know its a problem on my part somewhere but both being white, I am clueless. This has been the same experience with landsat images.

Is there a place I am losing my values?
[image: GEE_ display]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I figured out one has to play around with the min and max visualization parameters. For snapshot, here are the visualization parameters for Sentinel-2 and Landsat8 TOA: for sentinel use min:0, max: 3000.  For Landsat 8 TOA use min: 5000,  max: 12000. I did this for both and the image was no longer blank white or black. See this videos - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNXCliP1QWs and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbd9uujEFfE

Furthermore, open the settings tool, play with the 'custom' dropdown next to range of values. The values filled in the min max boxes under the custom stretches can be used to specify and customize your min max in the GEE code!